# Write a query for this table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Imagine that i have a table like below,i want to write a query that give me below result,is it possible?

[image]

Result:

```
100 , 2015-01-01 , ABC , XYZ
```

Comment: is any variation in data

Comment: Probably you should define your requirement more precisely. Right now it is too vague. Also - have you tried anything by yourself or it is "write code for me" request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `PIVOT`.

**Query**

```
select userid, 
[date],
[job],
[address]
from
(
    select userid,name,[value] from tblName
)
as s
pivot 
(
   max([value]) for [name] in ([date], [job], [address])
) as p;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/df725/1)

---

**`OR`**

**Query**

```
select userid,
max(case when name = 'date' then [value] else null end) as [date],
max(case when name = 'job' then [value] else null end) as job,
max(case when name = 'address' then [value] else null end) as address
from tblName
group by userid;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/df725/2)

Answer (score 0):

Another way,

try using `Group_Concatenate` and `Common Table Expression`

```
;with cte as

(select userid,
STUFF((
 SELECT ',' + md.[value]
 FROM tblName md
 WHERE m.userid = md.userid
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
as result
from tblName m group by m.userid
)

select (cast(userid as varchar(50))+','+result) as res from cte
```

see [Demo Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/df725/7)